# Boot to black screen, can't access terminal, after trying to fix login loop by installing fglrx

Tags: 14.04

Well, yes. So I spilled water on my laptop and downloaded FileZilla and set up some stuff for ftp, which I have never done before so I may have done something strange. I don't know what caused this.

Originally I got into a login loop, though I could log in in the guest account.

Then while trying to fix the login loop, I deleted my `.Xauthority` file. At one point it was booting to a black screen but if I typed in my password and hit enter, I could hear the login failed noise. At that point I could also access the terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>. I installed `gdm` and that restored the login screen but the login loop persisted. So I went back to the regular display, using `lightdm`.

The latest thing I've done was install `fglrx` and now it boots to a black screen and I can't access the terminal. I can get to bios by holding <kbd>Esc</kbd> during boot up - not by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> nor <kbd>C</kbd>. I don't know how to get to grub.

Several months ago, I had a problem after updating and had to switch to using the older kernel, 25, not 26. I'm using 14.04. My graphics card is nvidia which I reckon has something to do with all this.

Comment: Well, spilling water over your computer is aweful enough :) You should check your hardware before trying to figure out any software issues. Please run `memtest` (selectable in the boot menu) and post the output of `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sd[xY]` for every of your hard drives and SSDs by editing your question.

Comment: @KarlRichter so memtest is run from grub right? But I can't open grub! I can get bios by pressing esc but no amount of pressing shift, esc, or c will take me to the grub menu.

Comment: My bad. Can help you, but someone else will. After she_he did, run `memtest` and `smartctl` nevertheless.